# Weird bug with Accounts.onCreatedUser

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Here is a weird bug I am having. First here is my code

```
User = {};

User._defaults = {
  emails : [],
  enabled : true
}

User.defaults = function(){
  var defaults = _.clone(User._defaults);
  return _.extend(defaults,{
    createdAt : new Date()
  });
}

Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){    
  console.log(User.defaults()); 
  // returns {emails: [ { address: 'francis@domain.com', verified: true } ], enabled: true}

  _.defaults(user, User.defaults());

  user.emails.push(user.services.linkedin.emailAddress);

  return user;
});
```

As you can see, when I call `User.defaults()` it returns an object with the `emails` array filled with the email address of the previous new use.

But what is even weirder, is that when I do this :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  console.log(User._defaults, User.defaults());

  user.enabled = true;
  user.emails = [];
  user.createdAt = new Date();
  // _.defaults(user, User.defaults());

  user.emails.push(user.services.linkedin.emailAddress);

  return user;
})
```

The logged `User.defaults()` actually return an object with the `emails` array empty.

Anyone has an idea what can cause this ??

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have to do with the Underscore `clone` function. If you read the [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#clone).

> Create a shallow-copied clone of the provided plain object. Any nested
>   objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.

The important part is the shallow copy. Your array is not an actual copy, it's just a reference. So you are always referring to the same array every time.

I would do the following.

```
User = {};
User.defaults = function(){
  return {
    emails : [],
    enabled : true,
    createdAt : new Date()
  }
}
```